# Cannot find all the data of my POSTed form?

Tags: html, node.js, forms

I'm uploading a file from my webpage to my nodejs server, which already works. The file is inside a form, along with some other input values, that I cannot find how to read.

HTML

```
<form class="modal-content" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/testupload"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="file" value="Upload file" name="file" id="input-upload">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Automatic Transcription" name="TESTCHECK">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Automatic subtitling">
            <select name="testSelect">
                <option value="en-us">US English</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button >Upload Media</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

nodejs

```
app.post("/testupload", (request, response, next) =>{
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files){
        //console.log(fields);
        console.log(files.file.name); //Correctly gets the filename
        //further file upload code

    });
    console.log(request);
    response.end();
});
```

When I POST the form, I can get the file input back, but can't find the other inputs&values anywhere in the request.

Comment: What about console.log(fields) ?

Comment: Any reason why your other input doesn't have a name property? (html)

Comment: The input values are in fields now, when I tested it earlier before I corrected my code it only returned an empty '{ }' so thats correct

Comment: @EvansM. Just made it really quick and dirty, and didn't yet fix it before I got something back in my POST, but thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc you can use events:

```
form.on('field', function(name, value) {
});
```

or

you could also reference directly via fields (as in the example on https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
```

From what I understand you need to correctly name the form fields (first try with a simple example, one input text field).

Comment: The input values are in fields now, when I tested it earlier before I corrected my code it only returned an empty '{ }' and didn't look at it again. Thanks!